# PowerBI Sort Columns in Matrix Visual

Tags: powerbi

I have a Matrix visual in Microsoft PowerBI with Australian 'States' as rows and 'Months Ago' as columns.

By default the Matrix shows my columns from 0 months ago to 12. I would like it to show from 12 months ago on the left to 0 months ago on the right.

```
+-------------------+-----------------------------+-------+
|                   | Months Ago                  |       |
+-------------------+-----------------------------+-------+
| State             | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | Total |
+-------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------+
| Queensland        | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 60    |
+-------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------+
| New South Wales   |    |    |    |    |    |    |       |
+-------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------+
| Victoria          |    |    |    |    |    |    |       |
+-------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------+
| South Australia   |    |    |    |    |    |    |       |
+-------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------+
| Western Australia |    |    |    |    |    |    |       |
+-------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------+
```

Currently I am only given the option to sort by the value type fields (ie revenue etc).

Is there any option to sort/order the Column Headers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is an option for you to sort column headers directly.

However, you can change the default sort order for the `Months Ago` column so that it will be reflected in general.

You can add a custom column `MonthSrt` = `12 - [Months Ago]` in query editor:

[image: MonthSrt]

(It won't work in DAX because of a [known issue](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Sort-by-another-column-error/td-p/61341))

Then you can select the `Months Ago` column and sort it by `MonthSrt`:

[image: custom sort]

The custom sort will be applied when you use the `Months Ago` column in visuals:

[image: result]

Comment: I wasn't aware of the 'Sort by Column' feature in the GUI so I'll give that a go.

Answer (score -1):

You can also make groups (1 to 1 items) al give them al logical number:

[image]

The order will change automaticly in the matrix

Answer (score -1):

The following solution worked for me to display the dates in descending order in a matrix:

[how to sort column dates in descending order of matrix in power bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657205/how-to-sort-column-dates-in-descending-order-of-matrix-in-power-bi)