# how to sort column dates in descending order of matrix in power bi

Tags: sorting, matrix, powerbi

I need to sort my column of matrix in decreasing order of dates. I there any option? check this image of [matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj9Et.png)
 I need to order from Jan-20 to Jan-19(this column is already sorted with dates column). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try grouping each column by giving numbers for example: Jan20 -> 1 ; Dec19 ->2 ; Nov19 -> 3 and so on. and order this grouped column in dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to add a new column to define the search order in the way you want, in this case by date descending. So if you add a custom column in your model like this:

[image]

You can use it to sort your matrix - select it, click your date column in the fields pane, click [Sort by Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-sort-by-column) button in Modeling tab and select the newly added column:

[image]

This will reverse the order of the column headers in the matrix:

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work in the latest version - 2.98.683.0. Firstly it doesn't like the # in front of the date. Secondly, it tells me I can't sort Date by [Date Sort] as it creates a circular dependency. I don't know why it's so hard just to do a reverse date sort in PowerBI, seems like a feature everyone would use. Edit: you have to make a copy of the original column in order to remove the dependency: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Error-cyclic-dependency-when-sorting-by-calculated-column/td-p/1085712 e.g. make a [Date2] for the vis